# Is std::vector guaranteed not to leave gaps between elements?

Tags: c++, stl, alignment

if I have struct

```
struct three
{
   char  a,b,c;
};
```

and I use compiler pragmas to make sure that sizeof three is 3 is it guaranteed that if I have `vector<three>`
that it wont insert gap between elements? 
aka
that 
`vec.data()`   wont look like this:

> abc_abc_abc_abc_abc_    (_ is empty space)

Comment: It is not guaranteed, there exist hardware which can not access an object that is not properly aligned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is guaranteed by the "contiguous storage" condition. It was added to the standard in C++03 although it was already common to implementations before that. It says words to the effect that for `0 <= n < vec.size()`, `&vec[n] == &vec[0] + n`.

Since `&vec[0]` has type `T*`, this only holds if the difference in bytes between consecutive elements is equal to `sizeof(T)`.

Answer (score 3):

No, nothing of that kind is guaranteed by the language standard, and the pragma is compiler-dependent. Check your compiler manual whether the compiler makes any guarantees.

You can check `sizeof(three)`, though, to determine whether the layout is as you desire. Arrays (and elements in a `vector`) have no external gaps, so if that value is 3, you're fine.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Yes, arrays are laid out with no gap between elements, and each element occupies `sizeof(T)` bytes. The only data gaps can come from internal padding at the end of the structure, which you could tell from a larger size.

Answer (score 3):

It will be laid out the same way as for an array of the struct.

That arrays layout however will depend on how your implementation choses to align and pad this struct; you can get a hint of how it does that by looking at the `sizeof(three)`.

Some compilers will allow you to change the alignment and padding with pragmas or attributes, but it rarely is a good idea, since the compiler manufacturer usually try to use an optimal alignment (based on speed and memory overhead)